# Error while using tensors with multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing.Process(as I want to execute on 4 cores of my machine) to speedup the execution of my code.
My aim is to predict on 4 test images in parallel using 4 tensorflow models(.pb file) which is a continuous process. So
before sending to process I had loaded all 4 models and passing all session variable and tensors (detection classes, boxes, scores, etc..) to 4 processes.
While doing so, I ended up with errors

**TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects**

**EOFError: Ran out of input**

After googling I found that, I have to load the model(.pb file) in each of the process itself.

I implemented the same, got executed in 4 different processes but ended up with more execution time

So is there any way, to overcome the above errors so that my execution time will become lesser.

Comment: You can use `tf.distribute.Strategy` to train and predict on multiple GPUs, multiple machines, or TPUs. Using this API, you can distribute your existing models and training code with minimal code changes. Use `tf.distribute.Strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset` distribute data on multiple devices. For information refer https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/input#tfdistributestrategyexperimental_distribute_dataset. Thanks!

Comment: My aim is not to train on multiple machine. Rather the aim is to parallelize the prediction for multiple inputs. If I load the model on each of the machines, it is taking time. So I want to load the model only once and use distributed processes to predict using that model.